# Correct Syntax for Filters in OpenSearch Hybrid Search Subqueries

Tags: opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I'm working on implementing a hybrid search in OpenSearch 2.11.1 and encountering some difficulties with the correct syntax for filters in my subqueries. Below is my current query structure:

```json
{
    "query": {
        "hybrid": {
            "queries": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "multi_match": {
                                    "query": "solar",
                                    "type": "most_fields",
                                    "fields": [
                                        "og_title^3",
                                        "og_description^2",
                                        "name^2",
                                        "href_filename^2",
                                        "content"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "filter": [
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "content_type": "text"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "neural": {
                                    "embedding": {
                                        "query_text": "solar",
                                        "model_id": "LTZ1F40B3USp5Eb6uqGR",
                                        "k": 5
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "filter": [
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "content_type": "text"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "size": "10",
    "_source": {
        "excludes": [
            "embedding"
        ]
    }
}
```

While executing this query, I'm facing the following error:

> TransportError(500, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'Index 1 out of bounds for length 1')

I'm not sure if this is due to a syntax error in my query or a more complex issue. Any guidance on the correct syntax for filters in hybrid search subqueries or insights into this error would be greatly appreciated.

What I've tried:

- Executed the query without any filters: Success
- Added a filter to only the first subquery: Success
- Added a filter to the neural subquery: Failed with Error

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution, but may help to guide in a more workable direction.

I too ran into this issue and noticed two things:

1. It seems to be a result of using "should" in both the bm25 and neural query filters. AWS support has instructed to me to open a support ticket as this is most likely a limitation/bug on their end.
2. You seem to be performing non-efficient KNN filtering (See [OS documentation](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/search-plugins/knn/filter-search-knn/#efficient-k-nn-filtering)). If this is not intended, then you may want to consider it, but keep in mind that this is only supported by the Lucene and FAISS engines. See below code snippet for efficient KNN filtering using one of these engines:

```
{
  "query": {
    "hybrid": {
      "queries": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "multi_match": {
                  "query": "solar",
                  "type": "most_fields",
                  "fields": [
                    "og_title^3",
                    "og_description^2",
                    "name^2",
                    "href_filename^2",
                    "content"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ],
            "filter": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "content_type": "text"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "neural": {
            "embedding": {
              "query_text": "solar",
              "model_id": "LTZ1F40B3USp5Eb6uqGR",
              "k": 5,
              "filter": {
                "bool": {
                  "filter": {
                    "term": {
                      "content_type": "text"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": "10",
  "_source": {
    "excludes": [
      "embedding"
    ]
  }
}
```